# How to perform the dreaded double hop with linked servers?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

The situation:
I have SERVER1, SERVER2, ACCESSDB on SERVER3.

I have successfully created a linked server connection from SERVER1 to SERVER3's ACCESSDB.

I want to be able to access the linked server on SERVER1 from SERVER2 (aka the double hop).

When I log into SERVER2 I get the good ol - "dont have permissions" issue when I test the connection. I checked SERVER3 logs and it says the incoming connection is ANONYMOUS. I need to be able to pass some (any) credentials to SERVER3 from SERVER2.

NO, I cannot use a SQL account. I have to use Windows Auth.

Yes, I need to use KERBEROS and set up SPNs. That's where my question comes in. How do I properly set up KERBEROS and delegation?

I want to be able to run

```
select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@SPID
```

from SERVER2 and have it return 'KERBEROS' and not 'NTLM'.

What specific commands do I need to run to properly set up KERBEROS/SPNs? How do I create this "chain"?

FYI - Both instances are NAMED instances on SQL2008 R2 Standard (x64).

Answer (score 4):

[Security Account Delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189580%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

And for [SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905162%28SQL.80%29.aspx) but still valid too

Basically

- Configure the server in AD
- Set up the SPN
- Use sp_addlinkedsrvlogin so useself = true